# Why to extend Django User model? Is it bettet than using One-To-One Link With a User Model (Profile)?

Tags: django, model, profile, extend

this is my first question here, nevertheless S.O. is my main point of reference and support while developing my coding skills with Django.

Thanks on advance to all people who is part of SO!

**My main question is**: Under your experience, in which situations you needed to extend User Model? is it a common thing to do? ... all tutorials and blogs I have read says ... "for example, if you want to use an email insted a username". But this doesn't sound like a real reason to me, I haven't found other reasons than this.

If I want to use email as username I can create a user-creation form with a field to get username and allowing only emails. This will perfecly solve the problem right?

In my case I followed Django official recommendation:

> it’s highly recommended to set up a custom user model, even if the
>   default User model is sufficient for you. This model behaves
>   identically to the default user model, but you’ll be able to customize
>   it in the future if the need arises.

So I did this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

I'm ready, but ready for what? Please enlight me.

**The second part of my question is**: Let's imagine in the future I want to register more information about the users of my blog (country, gender, etc.) ... is it possible to create a profile table and point it with 1-to-1 relationship to my extended User model (which does nothing but is ready for the future)? Should I do it now that I have already dropped and created the database again?

Thanks a lot and sorry if I wrote too much.

Best regards,
goka.

Answer (score 0):

If your website need to collect more user information, like, company, telephone, zip code. Also, maybe you need to classify user, like, level_1, level_2, something haven't be define in User model. Then, it's better to create a profile model.

If you already have some user registered, then you add new profile model, it may cause your future coding very messy, like, one year later, you or other software engineer may assume all User have 'profile', and directly use user.profile.something without checking whether profile exists or not or a user, that will throw exception.

Comment: Thanks miao. Given the 2 options, use a Profile model or extend User model and add extra fields there. I prefer second one. Why? I find it easier ... hope not making a mistake since this is a newbie decision, and that's why I wrote this question. I want to avoid Profile solution since I believe signals are something more complex. Now I already have extended my User model and successfully added new section to Admin page for my new fields. I guess (and hope) I won't need anything else besides this.

Comment: Usually there won't be any problem to extend User model. When create a new User, don't forget this 'extend' model, and save this model.